# Como passar uma expressão lambda como argumento de um parâmetro em um método?

Tags: vb.net, expressões-lambda

Existe alguma forma de passar uma expressão lambda como argumento de um parâmero em um método? Como por exemplo:

```
Private Sub Metodo(Expressao As ?)
    Lista = Lista.Where(Expressao)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A forma mais adotada é usar um delegado pré-definido, como o [`Func(Of TSource, Boolean)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0):

```
Private Sub Metodo(Of TSource)(Expressao As Func(Of TSource, Boolean))
    Lista = Lista.Where(Expressao)
End Sub
```

O `TSource` é genérico, se souber o tipo específico pode usá-lo. Se for um `Integer`, pode ser:

```
Private Sub Metodo(Expressao As Func(Of Integer, Boolean))
    Lista = Lista.Where(Expressao)
End Sub
```

Para chamar não é tão conveniente quanto C#:

```
Metodo(Function(x) x = 0)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Lambda.vb).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Answer (score 4):

*Código:*

```
Public Class Prj
    Public Sub Metodo(Of T)(Where As Func(Of T, Boolean))
        Lista = Lista.Where(Where)
    End Sub
End Class
```

*Como utilizar?*

```
Dim c As New Prj
c.Metodo(Function(a) a = 1);
```

***Referencias***

- [How to make Parameters of VB.NET function as Generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255014/how-to-make-parameters-of-vb-net-function-as-generic-type)
- [Generic Types in Visual Basic (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [How to: Use a Generic Class (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79btc5zc.aspx)
- [Lambda Expressions (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253(v=vs.110).aspx)